# gzipped custom xml file on hdfs that needs to be indexed using solr (cloudera search)

Tags: hadoop, solr, cloudera, oozie, solrcloud

I'm big data newbie equipped with cloudera platform and 20Gb's gzipped xml file, that is dump to HDFS everyday.
This xml is custom and looks something like this:

```
<item> 
    <name>Peter</name>
    <domainCodes>
      <codeId>1</codeId>
      <description>Random descr</description>
    </domainCodes>
</item>
<item> 
   <name>Peter</name>
   <logicCodes>
      <codeId>2</codeId>
      <description>Random descr2</description>
   </logicCodes>
</item>
```

I consider every item in xml as a unit I want to index. You can see that tags inside this xml differ (domainCodes is sometimes logicCodes).

Question is how to index this file and pass it to solr. First problem i see is how to unzip this file and index it because solr takes only xml in format like this:

```
 <doc>
    <field name="id">adata</field>
    <field name="compName_s">A-Data Technology</field>
    <field name="address_s">46221 Landing Parkway Fremont, CA 94538</field>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">apple</field>
    <field name="compName_s">Apple</field>
    <field name="address_s">1 Infinite Way, Cupertino CA</field>
  </doc>
```

I read that there is something like cloudera search that is on top of solr and provides integration with big data stuff. Can you help me how to do this in big data world?
The only think i come up with is to make oozie workflow with some java action that will parse this xml to make it solr compatible and then index it, but parsing such big file is not best choice a guess and there must be a better one.
Thing to consider that maybe helpful: this xml file will be mapped to Hive
tables, maybe would be better to create indexes using those tables?

Comment: "this xml file will be mapped to Hive tables" -- seriously? How do you expect to do that - shredding the XML in smaller chunks, Mahout-style, then running a distributed XSLT parsing step?

Comment: This xml is mapped to Hive using Xml SerDe